# Help calling class from a class above

Tags: python

How to call from class oneThread: back to class fun:? As in, address a class written below. Is it possible?

```
class oneThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)
                self.start()

        def run(self):            
            print "1"
            time.sleep(1)
            print "2"
            time.sleep(1)
            print "3"
            self.wTree.get_widget("entryResult").set_text("Done with One.") # How to call from here back to class fun, which of course is below...? 

class fun:
        wTree = None
        def __init__( self ):                
                self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML( "main.glade" )
                self.wTree.signal_autoconnect( {"on_buttonOne" : self.one} )              
                gtk.main()

        def one(self, widget):
                oneThread();

gtk.gdk.threads_init()         
do=fun()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass the `fun` instance to the `oneThread` constructor:

```
class oneThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        ...

class fun:
    def one(self, widget):
        oneThread(self):
```

Comment: or just pass wTree, if that's all you care about.

Comment: I get an error: AttributeError: 'oneThread' object has no attribute 'wTree'

@dash-tom-bang can you give me an example please.

Comment: rename all instances of 'fun' in the above example to 'wTree'.

Comment: Not working. AttributeError: fun instance has no attribute 'get_widget'. What could be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the right references to the full object
or just a field of (the wTree).

**self.fun.wTree**  *if you pass self to the oneThread class*

**self.wTree** *if you pass the gtk.glade.XML Object*

see the comments...

```
class oneThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, reference):
        self.fun = reference
        #or self.wTree = reference
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        print "1"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "2"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "3"
        self.fun.wTree.get_widget("entryResult").set_text("Done with One.")
        # or self.wTree.get_widget("entryResult").set_text("Done with One.")

class fun(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML( "main.glade" )
        self.wTree.signal_autoconnect( {"on_buttonOne" : self.one} )
        gtk.main()

    def one(self, widget):
        oneThread(self)
        # or oneThread(self.wTree)
```

Answer (score 1):

The elegant solution would be to pass the reference to class fun instance to the oneThread constructor, as other suggested, but you seem to be trying to do something else: making the fun class as singleton an accessing it as a global object. Is that right? That is usually a bad idea, but sometimes makes sense.

If that is the case, then you are making two mistakes:

1. you use `self.fun` in `oneThread.run`, although 'fun' is not part of the  oneThread class or its instance. You should be using just 'fun' to access the class 'fun'. It doesn't matter it is defined below, as the code will be executed when the class is already defined.
2. in `fun.__init__` you are not writting the class attribute `fun.wTree`, but creating a instance attribute `wTree`. The class attribute `fun.wTree` will stay `None`. To change it
   use `fun.wTree = gtk.glade.XML( "main.glade" )` instead (though, you may keep using `self.wTree` to access it later).

So the code would look like this:

```
class oneThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.start()

    def run(self):            
        print "1"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "2"
        time.sleep(1)
        print "3"
        fun.wTree.get_widget("entryResult").set_text("Done with One.") 

class fun:
    wTree = None
    def __init__( self ):                
            fun.wTree = gtk.glade.XML( "main.glade" )
            self.wTree.signal_autoconnect( {"on_buttonOne" : self.one} )              
            gtk.main()

    def one(self, widget):
            oneThread();

gtk.gdk.threads_init()         
do=fun()
```

I would also suggest renaming `wTree` attribute to `instance` in such case too.

And once more: this (using a singleton as a kind of global variable) is probably not the way to go.